# How to feed a DB PostgreSQL/PostGIS through data that are in Informix DB?

Tags: postgresql

I do not have much experience in postgresql but would like some clues on how to do the following:

I intend to feed a DB PostgreSQL/PostGIS through data that are in Informix DB, which I have access via ODBC.
In short, I intend to do a "select" in Informix DB and be able to import that information directly into a DB PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

From what I understood it seems possible to do it via DBLink. Is that so? 
Where can I get detailed information about this process?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dump the data from whatever DB you have in text format like CSV, then use COPY command to load the data into PostgreSQL.